# Value is not transfered from a class to another JAVA

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have problems with idS. in sellContainer idS is 1 and in sellCtr is always 0 so the method addItemToSell is not working. Always give null pointer exception.

```
public class SellCtr{
    private SellContainer sellContainer;
    private OrderLineSell ols;

    private int idS;
    private int idOls;

    public SellCtr(){
       sellContainer = SellContainer.getInstance();
    }

    public void createSell(String date, Customer c, Employee e){
       Sell sell = new Sell(date,c,e);
       sellContainer.addSell(sell);
       idS = sell.getId();
    } 

    public void addItemToSell(OrderLineSell orderLineSell){
       sellContainer.findSell(idS).addOrderLineSell(orderLineSell);
    }

    public int getId(){
       return idS;
    }

    public int getIdOls(){
       return idOls;
    }

    public Sell findSell(int idS){
      return sellContainer.findSell(idS);
    }
}
```

and the other class is :

```
public class SellContainer{
    private ArrayList<Sell> sales;
    private static int idS=0;
    private static SellContainer instance=null;

    public SellContainer(){
        sales = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static SellContainer getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new SellContainer();
        }
        return instance;
    } 

    public void addSell(Sell s){
        idS++;
        s.setId(idS);
        sales.add(s);


    }

    public Sell findSell(int idS){
        for(Sell sell : sales){
            if(sell.getId()==idS){
                return sell;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the error :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at controlLayer.SellCtr.addItemToSell(SellCtr.java:24)
at tuiLayer.SaleAddItemToSaleGUI$2.actionPerformed(SaleAddItemToSaleGUI.java:93)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have rebuild the project and the exceptions changed.

EDIT 3 : I have made idS static and now it works. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: You claim you're getting a NullPointerException, but your stack trace says otherwise: "Unresolved compilation problem: The method getId() is undefined for the type SellCtr". I would strongly recommend that you don't try to run code that doesn't compile.

Comment: My code compiles, but when it reaches that line, it breaks and pops that error. How can I fix it?

Comment: If your code had compiled when you posted the question, you wouldn't get that exception, would you? Always pay attention to what you're posting - you clearly *had* a compilation error, even if you've now fixed it.

Comment: Now, presumably `findSell` is returning `null` - which it will do if you haven't called `createSell`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you

- make sure you are compiling all your classes. A build tool like maven or gradle will help.
- you use `enum` for singletons.  These are thread safe and simpler.
- disable the feature in eclipse which allows you to run code which doesn't compile.  This only delays finding errors which makes them worse.

I would replace

```
public class SellContainer{
    private ArrayList<Sell> sales;
    private static int idS=0;
    private static SellContainer instance=null;

    public SellContainer(){
        sales = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static SellContainer getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new SellContainer();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

with

```
public enum SellContainer {
    INSTANCE;
    private final List<Sell> sales = new ArrayList<>();
    private int idS = 0;
```

Comment: How can I disable that feature?

Comment: @RobertIvan I don't use eclipse, but those I have seen use this feature it causes them grief in the long run.

Comment: And why is enum better than singleton?

Comment: @RobertIvan: It's not "better than a singleton" - it's using `enum` as an easy way of *implementing* the singleton pattern.

Comment: @RobertIvan it's better than writing your own code for a singleton which might have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Initiate the object before the return object is back to the called method.
In SellContainer, if condition failure leads to give back the Sell Object as NULL.
You need to modify this logic.

**return null;**